# NS2 Program in Fedora (Tcl program is not running)

Tags: tcl

In the terminal this error is occured:

```
[nandha@localhost tcl8.5.8]$ tclsh ns-simple.tcl
invalid command name "new"
while executing
"new Simulator"
invoked from within
"set ns [new Simulator]"
(file "ns-simple.tcl" line 3):
```

How to resolve it in ns2 fedora ..

Comment: This does not seem to be a `C#` issue, I've retagged it.

Comment: The command `new` is not defined, and there's nothing much more to it that can be found from the given error.

Comment: NS2 scripts require quite a lot of extra packages (their `new` is part of OTcl if I remember right) including some custom ones specific to network simulation. Is there an `ns` or `ns2` program on the system that you can use instead? (It'll be a _heavily extended_ `tclsh`…)